# Turning progress display off globally for angular-cli v6

Tags: angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

Upgraded to Angular 6. Now I want to turn progress display off globally for `ng build`. However, the documentation about the `ng config` command which apparently replaced `ng set/get` seems to be missing or out-of-date. I think I need to do the following:

```
ng config --global some.path.progress false
```

But I can't figure out what the `some.path` part needs to be. Whatever I try I get an "Invalid path" error.

Of course I could also just edit `~/.angular.json`, if I knew what the right hierarchy of keys was. This doesn't work:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "cli": {
    "defaults": {
      "build": {
        "progress": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Within a specific `angular.json` file, the `progress` option works if placed under `options` key inside `build`. However, it seems to be ignored in the `~/.angular.json` file even if included inside `options`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set a build progress option at a global level.

The only CLI options that you can set at a global level are the following. I gleaned this from the code [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/894e0087303c40b0cd5e0460d9e25c753e79cab9/packages/%40angular/cli/commands/config.ts#L28).

```
cli.warnings.versionMismatch (boolean)
cli.warnings.typescriptMismatch (boolean)
cli.defaultCollection (string)
cli.packageManager (string)
```

You can set this option at the project level (as you said in your post). This is the command you would use to do that.

```
ng config projects['projectname'].architect.build.options.progress false
```

Or

```
ng config projects.projectname.architect.build.options.progress false
```

Of course, set the property to `true` to turn progress back on.

Comment: Thanks. Not allowing that seems like a questionable and arbitrary design decision.

Comment: I agree. I think they should expand what can be set globally, at a minimum for defaults when creating a new project.