# No config found or get/set have been deprecated in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

```
ng config --global defaults.styleExt=scss
```

> Error: config not found

```
ng set --global defaults.styleExt=scss
```

> Error: get/set have been deprecated in favor of the config command.

**Installed Packages versions**

ngular CLI: 6.0.3

Node: 8.11.1

Angular: 6.0.2

@angular/cli                      6.0.3

@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.3

webpack                           4.8.3

**update**

The following command gave me an error in the image

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component '{ styleext: "scss"}'
```

[image]

Comment: it should be ```ng set defaults.styleExt scss --global```

Comment: This answer may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187466/turning-progress-display-off-globally-for-angular-cli-v6/50189857#50189857

Comment: when I run the command `ng set --global default.styleExt=scss`, it gave me such warning `get/set have been deprecated in favor of the config command.`

Comment: May I ask for down voting reason? Did I ask irrelevant or illogical or incomplete question?

Comment: You are running that command with the global install of the angular cli (v6), thats why you see the warning, but your project seems to have been created with cli v1.x.x. The config file structures are different for those versions.

Comment: Whether I should remove the global version and update the local cli and the run the command or what else do you recommend?

Answer (score 3):

`ng set --global defaults.styleExt=scss` is deprecated since ng6.

You should use:

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component '{ styleext: "scss"}'
```

If you want to target a specific project (replace {project} with your project's name):

```
ng config projects.{project}.schematics.@schematics/angular:component '{ styleext: "scss"}'
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, I'll test it :)

Comment: I updated my question, please have a look. I got an error shown in the image in my question

Answer (score 0):

For your version you need to do this:

On terminal install this:

```
npm install node-sass
```

After this you need to rename .css files in your project to .scss and change all the calls of css to scss in your others files.

Comment: for a moment, this is good but I want to configure it once for all new angular projects to `scss` so that I should not include `--style=scss` in every project.